# Facebook App Advanced Settings

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**I know this is really dumb** but I'm trying to find the advanced settings for a Facebook app I made yesterday.

I can go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ but when I click on it there isn't any type of `Advanced Settings` button. I click on `Save Changes` but I still don't see where the advanced settings are.

Does anyone have the exact url I can use to see `Advanced Settings`? I don't know why it's not showing up for me.

[image]

Comment: This happened to me too. No clue why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your original url is like `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app_id>/summary/` go to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app_id>/advanced/` for the advanced page.

Comment: this happened to me too. I just had to type it in like mvdnes suggested. I think something's wrong with fbook.